# AWS lambda documentClient.put error when trying to put data

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am facing this timeout error in aws editor(nodejs environment). I understand that there maybe be timeout set for 3 seconds, still this small code should run easily within 3 secs. Also, I have used other methods to put data in my dynamoDB like `batchWrite` and it works fine!

```
Response:
{
  "errorMessage": "2021-02-08T15:58:57.631Z 66890dfe-6f3a-42ae-b689-510bb8027a9d Task timed out after 3.03 seconds"
}
```

*My code:*

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient(
    {
        region:'ap-south-1'
    });

exports.handle = function(event , context ,callback)  {
     var params = {
            TableName: 'guestbook',
         Item:{
             "date":Date.now(),
             "message":"I love your website"
         }
       };
    
  docClient.put(params, function(err,data){
      
      if(err){
      callback(err,null);
      }
      else{
      callback(null,data);
      }
  });
    
};
```

I am trying to put data into my dynamoDB,.
My role policy is

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "dynamodb:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Is your Lambda function running in a VPC?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42457997/aws-lambda-node-js-timeout-when-trying-to-access-dynamodb

Comment: Sorry but as a beginner I don't know much about that feature and have certainly not used that

Comment: Also,  I have used other methods to put data in my dynamoDB like`batchWrite` and it works fine